# Which is the correct version of Pixi for Phaser?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, pixi.js

Some time ago I was building a little game with PIXI and Phaser js.

Now I see I have an old version of PIXI for Phaser, which actually has not defined the following for some reason:

PIXI.CanvasPool

I am building with browserify. The problem is I don't see PIXI as a dependency of Phaser in package.json defined.

After I updated both libraries and I have this versions:

PIXI 2.4.4

Phaser 3.0.8

And keep on having the same problem.

I would like to know which version of PIXI should I have for Phaser?

Comment: From what I know, removing the dependency on PIXI is in the roadmap for Phaser 3 - they're writing their own renderer from the ground up. What you're seeing is probably leftover code as it's still work in progress.

Comment: That is correct. One of the main goals of phaser 3 is to exchange Pixi with its own renderer. While phaser 3 is under extremely active development, it's still far away from a stable library and it should't be used for production... or even development to be honest! You can keep an eye for dev logs on the [labs page](http://phaser.io/labs) of phaser.

Comment: Great thanks to both of you. I will keep an eye to las page you comme t @Apovtx if you post a formal answer would be great though, so I can mark as correct.

Comment: i've already posted an answer bellow :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've posted your version numbers the wrong way around. I'm pretty sure what you've actually got installed is Phaser 2.4.4 and PIXI 3.0.8.

Phaser does not use a mainstream version of Pixi (it hasn't done for a long time now). The version of Pixi included with Phaser 2 has been considerably customised and cannot be simply swapped out with another version. This is also the reason it's not a dependency in the package.json. You must use the version included in the Phaser source.

Comment: I see your point. I installed Phaser through npm, so I should go for node_modules/phaser/src/pixi/Pixi.js.
As this is the customised version of pixi for phaser.

Comment: It makes more clear now, for instance if I want a physic engine I should go to src and see the physics engine I need for example p2. So I can take what I need from there, thx.

Comment: Yes this is correct. For p2 it's a little different in that you are far more likely to have success swapping out p2.js from the Phaser src folder with a newer release, and it's very likely to 'just work' (depending on if it's a major breaking release or not). Pixi however is our own fork of it.

Answer (score 1):

As i've said in the comment phaser 3 is not using pixi. The latest stable phaser version, v2.4.4 "Amador", is using Pixi.js v2.2.9.

**Edit:**  You can read development logs in the [phaser labs](http://phaser.io/labs) page

Comment: photonstorm make it very clear how to manage dependencies for phaser

Answer (score 0):

I can see that working with examples from the repository

https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-examples

Will have the correct versioning for the libraries, I was wondering if there is a place where I can see how to resolve this dependencies, otherwise I will be using a version of those examples that probably is not the latest one but actually resolves my dependencies correctly.